# Fancy header line

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to construct a header line which looks like this.

[image]

How do I do it? Does `fancyhdr` support this kind of header line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with `fancyhdr` by redefining `\headrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{e-ISSN}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
    \color{red!33!black}\vspace{-8pt}%
    \thickhrulefill{.6pt}

    \vspace{-9pt}\thickhrulefill{2.4pt}%
}
\begin{document}
A page to show the header. 
\end{document}
```

[image]